# Angular ng-show is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I am using ng-show in below **html code:**

```
 <span ng-show="show_notif_count=1" class="m-alert" id="notif_count">{{notif_count}}</span>
```

**js code:**

```
$scope.show_notif_count = 0;
    $http.get('count/',{headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
    .success(function(response)
    {
        console.log($scope.show_notif_count);
        if(response>2)
        {
            $scope.show_notif_count = 1;
            console.log(response);
            $scope.notif_count = response;
        }

    });
```

The problem is ng-show never hides the span and it always keeps on showing. I have tried using "==" instead of "=" and also other values for "show_notif_count" but either it always shows up or always keeps hiding. what could be wrong with above code?

Comment: what are you getting in response?

Comment: I get 3, 4 or anything greater than 2. My condn is getting satisfied as I am verifying it by alert or console.log.

Comment: I am getting integer value in response.

Comment: don't write service in controller. Write a different service. because .success() is less frequent than .than()

Comment: Try to display {{show_notif_count}} while debugging. Maybe you should use $apply

Answer (score 3):

`show_notif_count=1` is set value for variable not to compare.

Update:

```
 <span ng-show="show_notif_count=1" class="m-alert" id="notif_count">{{notif_count}}</span>
```

To:

```
 <span ng-show="show_notif_count === 1" class="m-alert" id="notif_count">{{notif_count}}</span>
```

Note: It will hide when `response <= 2`, please check response again.

Comment: I have updated "=" to "===" now it always stay hidden. I see following html in firebug "<span id="notif_count" class="m-alert ng-hide" ng-show="show_notif_count===1">2</span>" in disabled form. I am taking care of all checks by printing things in console log.

Comment: `response <= 2` => `notif_count = response` => It will hide

Comment: my conditions are working fine and when I console log "show_notif_count" it gives 1. Then why span does not show up?

Comment: Can you give me demo link?